# Weird result of 2 * 2i in Golang

Tags: go

Per [this](https://talks.godoc.org/github.com/davecheney/presentations/gopher-puzzlers.slide#15)

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

var i = 2

func main() {
    j := 2 * 2i
    fmt.Println(j)
}
```

Why the result is `(0+4i)`? Could someone explain it clearly?

Comment: `2i` is a complex number.`2 * 2i = 4i`. I think you want `2 * 2 * i`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go has [complex numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number) as a built-in numeric type, including support for complex literals. They're a relatively obscure feature, but they use a fairly standard notation.

The reason for the confusion may be that you have this variable `i`. That variable is actually **not used** in your program. The "i" character you see in `2 * 2i` is actually being consumed by the complex number literal. It is not related to the variable `i`.

Try moving the variable declaration down like this:

```golang
func main() {
    var i = 2
    j := 2 * 2i
    fmt.Println(j)
}
```

and you'll see that you actually get a compiler error:
`i declared but not used`

You can see the documentation for the language feature here: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Imaginary_literals